# tippy() showing [object Object] after passing the right object the component

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, tippyjs, react-tippy

I have 35 images in a section  and on hovering these images I want to show a tooltip using a component. I have created a tooltip manually and using tippy.js but somehow I am facing the issue below:
It is only showing [object Object] when I hover.

**this is my section jsx file**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './SectionTwo.sass';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { useCopyToClipboard } from 'usehooks-ts';
import UserTooltip from '../UserTooltip/UserTooltip';
import tippy from 'tippy.js';

const SectionTwo = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('data/userDetails.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data=> setUsers(data))  
    },[])

    

    useEffect(() => {
        const getUser = (id) =>{
            return users.find(user => user._id === id);
        }
        for (let i = 1; i <= 35; i++) {
            const userToDisplay = getUser(i);
            

            tippy(`#image-${i}`, {
                content: <UserTooltip user={userToDisplay}/>,
                placement: 'bottom'
            });
        }
    }, [users]);

    

    const [value, copy] = useCopyToClipboard()
    const generateRandomString = () => {
        let result = '';
        const characters =
          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        const charactersLength = characters.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
          result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*charactersLength));
        }
        return result;
    };


    const notification = ()=>{
        copy(generateRandomString());
        toast.success('copied', {
            position: "top-right",
            autoClose: 5000,
            hideProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            theme: "light",
            });
    }
    

    return (
        <div className='section-two'>
            <div className='text-section'>
                <h1 className='heading'>Join the Squad</h1>
                <p className='description'>Claim your name, wear it on Twitter and become a Proliferator of the nounish revolution.</p>
                <p className='noggles'>Wear your noggles  <span><button onClick={notification}><img src="images/copy.png" alt="" /></button></span></p>
                <ToastContainer/>
                
            </div>
            <div className='image-container-lg'>
                <img src="images/users/user1.png" alt="" id="image-1" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user2.png" alt="" id="image-2" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user3.png" alt="" id="image-3" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user4.png" alt="" id="image-4" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user5.png" alt="" id="image-5" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user6.png" alt="" id="image-6" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user7.png" alt="" id="image-7" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user8.png" alt="" id="image-8" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user9.png" alt="" id="image-9" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user10.png" alt="" id="image-10" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user11.png" alt="" id="image-11" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user12.png" alt="" id="image-12" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user13.png" alt="" id="image-13" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user14.png" alt="" id="image-14" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user15.png" alt="" id="image-15" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user16.png" alt="" id="image-16" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user17.png" alt="" id="image-17" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user18.png" alt="" id="image-18" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user19.png" alt="" id="image-19" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user20.png" alt="" id="image-20" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user21.png" alt="" id="image-21" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user22.png" alt="" id="image-22" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user23.png" alt="" id="image-23" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user24.png" alt="" id="image-24" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user25.png" alt="" id="image-25" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user26.png" alt="" id="image-26" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user27.png" alt="" id="image-27" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user28.png" alt="" id="image-28" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user29.png" alt="" id="image-29" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user30.png" alt="" id="image-30" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user31.png" alt="" id="image-31" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user32.png" alt="" id="image-32" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user33.png" alt="" id="image-33" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user34.png" alt="" id="image-34" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user35.png" alt="" id="image-35" className="img" />
            </div>
            <div className='image-container-sm'>
                <img src="images/users/user1.png" alt="" id="image-1" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user2.png" alt="" id="image-2" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user3.png" alt="" id="image-3" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user4.png" alt="" id="image-4" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user5.png" alt="" id="image-5" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user6.png" alt="" id="image-6" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user7.png" alt="" id="image-7" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user8.png" alt="" id="image-8" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user9.png" alt="" id="image-9" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user10.png" alt="" id="image-10" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user11.png" alt="" id="image-11" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user12.png" alt="" id="image-12" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user13.png" alt="" id="image-13" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user14.png" alt="" id="image-14" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user15.png" alt="" id="image-15" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user16.png" alt="" id="image-16" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user17.png" alt="" id="image-17" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user18.png" alt="" id="image-18" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user19.png" alt="" id="image-19" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user20.png" alt="" id="image-20" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user21.png" alt="" id="image-21" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user22.png" alt="" id="image-22" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user23.png" alt="" id="image-23" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user24.png" alt="" id="image-24" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user25.png" alt="" id="image-25" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user26.png" alt="" id="image-26" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user27.png" alt="" id="image-27" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user28.png" alt="" id="image-28" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user29.png" alt="" id="image-29" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user30.png" alt="" id="image-30" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user31.png" alt="" id="image-31" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user32.png" alt="" id="image-32" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user33.png" alt="" id="image-33" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user34.png" alt="" id="image-34" className="img" />
                <img src="images/users/user35.png" alt="" id="image-35" className="img" />
            </div>
            {/* {
                users.slice(0,1).map(user => <UserTooltip key={user._id} user={user}/>)
            } */}
        </div>
    );
};

export default SectionTwo;
```

**This is my tooltip jsx file**

```
import React from 'react';
import './UserTooltip.sass'

const UserTooltip = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    const {user} = props;
    const {name, picture, about, link} = user;
    return (
        <div className='tooltip'>
            <img className="user-image" src={picture} alt="" />
            <h2 className='user-name'>{name} <span><img src="images/username.png" alt="" /></span></h2>
            <p className='user-details'>{about.slice(0,150)}</p>
            <a href={link} target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UserTooltip;
```

live page shows [object Object] while hovering.
**Screenshot:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf8OI.png)

This is what it should look like when live:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxbvp.png)